Should KCC remove automatically-created connection Objects after I manually delete a SITELINK?
Very basic question
I've created a sitelink between 2 Active Directory Sites and KCC internally auto creates object connections between dessignated domain controllers /Bridgeheadservers on each of those sites, and then DCs replicate. Everything is cool there.
But what should happen with those automatically-created-by-kcc-object-connections when I manually delete the sitelink because,lets say, i dont want the sites to replicate no more?  Should KCC should remove them after x period of time? or should I manually removed them?
Im getting different answers and just looking for the official response, since my on lab testings the auto obj connections in both sites are NOT getting removed by KCC after Sitelink deletion and I dont know if that's by design or not.
THanks

Is the Bridge All Site Links option checked in the IP properties under Inter-Site Transports?
It's enabled by default, and if there are no explicitly configured site link bridges, ISTG (intersite topology generator) will create the bridges itself according to site link costing and any sites linking to a common site. This article shows what the option looks like in Sites and Services and explains how it works, with diagrams.
Note: KCC runs at 15 minute intervals by default, including calculating the bridgehead servers, so replication topology changes will show up then. Or if you don't care about extra replication, you run it immediately with repadmin /kcc * (note this will run against all DCs - you can target a site with repadmin /kcc site:MYSITE).
The ISTG runs every 30 minutes. There is one ISTG generator DC per site. If the other DCs detect there's been no ISTG activity over 60 minutes, they assign a new DC to the role. Lots of info on topology generation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/cc961781(v=technet.10)

thx for all the info but I dont think its related to my question.


KCC creates obj connections when a SITELINK is created (just 1 sitelink in this case, not even defaultsitelink present for testing purposes)


I go and delete the SITELINK manually.  What should happen with the obj connections that kcc auto created under NTDS?


Thx

Do what I suggested and check if Bridge All Site Links is enabled. If it is, turn it off and see what happens.

Just did. Found the feature enabled and I turned it off, and then removed the Sitelink. The objects are still there.

Since there are no sitelinks and BASL is turned off, the DCs can't replicate any more? In that instance, I imagine KCC would not clean up any "old" configs. The proof might be to delete them from the PDCE (or any DC, but the PDCE initiates replication in the domain) in ADSIEdit and see if anything "magically" reappears after KCC runs? I'm assuming there are only two sites and repadmin /replsum shows replication is busted. Also (I should have thought of this before), if you demote a DC, an important task is to clean up the replication object under NTDS for the site - metadata cleanup.

The DCs are still replicating intersite because the connection objects that KCC created are still there, the only thing that has been removed is the sitelink itself.

Yes, I got the connections are still there. Further to the metadata clean-up process for manually removing demoted DCs from NTDS Settings (it's sometimes needed even after a graceful demotion) and from replication partners, it's also a required procedure for forest recovery - recover one DC, then delete all other DC objects and replication partners. To sum up, my assumption is that if KCC can't calculate new replication partners for any reason, it simply does nothing.

I've always manually checked and cleaned up as needed after DC demotion/site reassignments for the last 24 years - however, I can't find any specific doco on whether KCC is not expected to expunge everything if sitelinks are removed. But my working assumption was that it did not, and your investigations seem to confirm that. If anyone does have a link to doco on what it is or is not supposed to do, that would be interesting.
